# Meteor: long latency when returning from server metod call

Tags: meteor

I do a Meteor.call.  I see the server execute its code and finish in less than one second.  Then, every once in a while, the client waits a very long time to receive the response.  This happens locally, so it isn't related to any internet connectivity issue.  The response consists of a quite small object, so I don't think it's a JSON parsing issue, either.

The point here is that the server is finished and has returned its response... but the client does not receive it for up to several minutes.

server code:

```
findComments : function(ne, sw, filter, timezoneOffset) {
    // ... do some Mongo queries and updates ... etc.  nothing too weird.

    console.log("returning now...");
    return result;
}
```

client code:

```
Meteor.call("findComments", ne, sw, filter, timezoneOffset, function(err, comments) {
    console.log("comments = " + comments);
    // ... and we're back
}
```

I can put a breakpoint in this "Meteor.call" line in the client code, and in the callback.  I see "returning now..." on the server, and then.... nothing.  I wait a couple minutes, and then I see the good result coming back to the client in the callback.

This behavior can be seen in Chrome, as well as on the installed app on Android and iOS.  It happens rarely, but is extremely disruptive, and we are not able to isolate any particular conditions leading to this.

What to do??

EDIT:

The client does eventually go into the callback, after about 2 minutes.  During this time, the CPU is idle.  I also tested this with a simple server call that takes no arguments and does nothing at all on the server... same effect.

So, if I stop execution on the client to see what he's up to during this time, it stops in this function, in lib/trans-websocket.js:

```
var WebSocketTransport = SockJS.websocket = function(ri, trans_url) {                                             // 1263
    var that = this;                                                                                              // 1264
    var url = trans_url + '/websocket';                                                                           // 1265
    if (url.slice(0, 5) === 'https') {                                                                            // 1266
        url = 'wss' + url.slice(5);                                                                               // 1267
    } else {                                                                                                      // 1268
        url = 'ws' + url.slice(4);                                                                                // 1269
    }                                                                                                             // 1270
    that.ri = ri;                                                                                                 // 1271
    that.url = url;                                                                                               // 1272
    var Constructor = _window.WebSocket || _window.MozWebSocket;                                                  // 1273
                                                                                                                  // 1274
    that.ws = new Constructor(that.url);                                                                          // 1275
    that.ws.onmessage = function(e) {     <-- RIGHT HERE IS WHERE IT STOPS                                                                          // 1276
        that.ri._didMessage(e.data);                                                                              // 1277
    };                                                                                                            // 1278
    // Firefox has an interesting bug. If a websocket connection is                                               // 1279
    // created after onunload, it stays alive even when user                                                      // 1280
    // navigates away from the page. In such situation let's lie -                                                // 1281
    // let's not open the ws connection at all. See:                                                              // 1282
    // https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client/issues/28                                                          // 1283
    // https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=696085                                                        // 1284
    that.unload_ref = utils.unload_add(function(){that.ws.close()});                                              // 1285
    that.ws.onclose = function() {                                                                                // 1286
        that.ri._didMessage(utils.closeFrame(1006, "WebSocket connection broken"));                               // 1287
    };                                                                                                            // 1288
};                                                                                                                // 1289
```

Oddly, any breakpoints I put in this code will be ignored.  But I can examine the value of the MessageEvent e:

```
bubbles    :    false
cancelBubble    :    false
cancelable    :    false
composed    :    false
currentTarget    :    WebSocket
data    :    "a["{\"msg\":\"updated\",\"methods\":[\"64\"]}"]"
defaultPrevented    :    false
eventPhase    :    2
isTrusted    :    true
lastEventId    :    ""
origin    :    "ws://localhost:3000"
path    :    Array[0]
ports    :    null
returnValue    :    true
source    :    null
srcElement    :    WebSocket
target    :    WebSocket
timeStamp    :    17400.095
type    :    "message"
__proto__    :    MessageEvent
```

Comment: that's really weird. can you post your code?

Comment: Sure, but there's not much to it.  I'll edit the question now.

Comment: Hey @Marc did you had any luck solving this?

Comment: Able to fix the issue by using Meteor.apply with onResultReceived option. Check below answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your function inside try/catch like this:

```
myFunction() {

      try {
             ...  
          } catch(e) {
              throw new Meteor.Error(e.code,e);
          }
}
```

Then in Meteor.call catch the error. Maybe error happend on server.

Comment: There is no error.  Like I said, the server code executes normally and returns a result in less than one second.  Then... the client (sometimes, unpredictably, and rarely) waits for several minutes before entering the callback.

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who is still looking for solution to this problem.
As it it mentioned in Meteor docs.

> Once the Method has finished running on the server, it sends a result message to the client with the Method ID generated in step 2, and the return value itself. The client stores this for later use, but doesn’t call the Method callback yet. If you pass the onResultReceived option to Meteor.apply, that callback is fired.

Ref: https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#advanced-boilerplate

So if you want your call back to be triggered once the server method return the value then you can use Metor.apply method with the option onResultReceived.

```
Meteor.apply(
  "findComments",
  [ne, sw, filter, timezoneOffset],
  {
    onResultReceived: function(err, comments) {
      console.log("comments = " + comments);
      // ... and we're back
    }
  }
```

Even I was struggling with the latency time but after doing above its instant.