# Meteor.call is very slow when responding back

Tags: meteor

I am facing performance problem with Meteor.call(). I have a method on server side which gets execute within a millisecond but when I seek a response in the client side, it is taking long to get the response data inside the callback function. Is anyone experience the problem before?

I was using Meteor 1.12.1 and updated to Meteor 2.1.1 hoping to solve the problem by updating but I didn't find any difference.

**Update:** I am facing issue on all environment (osx, linux, windows).

For eg: This is my server code

```
Meteor.methods({
   newEntry() {
     //This method is executed within millisecond
   }
})
```

This is my client code

```
function submitEntry(data) {
    Meteor.call(
        'newEntry',
        data,
        (error, res) => {
            //Here I am getting the response after long wait. 
        },
    );
}
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Does that happen with *all* your methods only one? I would imagine this depends on the method itself. Any way you can create a minimal reproducible example? If not, please just post your whole method, and in particular the code you used to verify that the method itself executes quickly.

Comment: The other question is how big the response is. If it is huge, it could simply be the time to send all the data.

Comment: My response is very small. Is just a string containing one word. I just found this question and I am on a same boat as this.  Can you check this as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225633/meteor-long-latency-when-returning-from-server-metod-call

Comment: All of the method I use Meteor.call is having same problem. The server method does not even take 1 sec but when I am getting response in the client side it takes long time. even if you do nothing on the server method it still takes long time.

Comment: I don't know how else to help without being able to reproduce this. Can you post your meteor project (trimmed down to just this issue) somewhere?

Comment: also, is this in dev or production?

Comment: it in dev. I am trying to figure out how I can post my project.

Comment: By any chance, do you still have `autopublish` package for prototyping, and a big database?

Comment: I solved the problem by using Meteor.apply with the option onResultReceived. See below comment for for information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. As per the Meteor docs.

> Once the Method has finished running on the server, it sends a result message to the client with the Method ID generated in step 2, and the return value itself. The client stores this for later use, but doesn’t call the Method callback yet. If you pass the onResultReceived option to Meteor.apply, that callback is fired.

Ref: https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#advanced-boilerplate

So if you want your call back to be triggered once the server method return the value then you can use Metor.apply method with the option onResultReceived.

```
Meteor.apply(
  "methodName",
  [...params],
  {
    onResultReceived: function() {
      // Whatever you want to do after callback. 
    }
  }
```