# Meteor very slow for method call on server

Tags: meteor, methods, server

I'm facing a very strange problem since Meteor update from v2.5.6 to v2.6.1:

When i deploy the app on my server (a local server in my LAN) using MUP at first glance everything works as expected. But when i call a method the first time, the answer is returned from the server very very slow (about 10-20 seconds). When calling then the same method again, it is quickly as usual. However this is the case for every method in my application.

Of course I also changed my MUP setup when updating from 2.5.6 to 2.6.1 and called `mup setup` first:

My changes in `mup.js`:

```js
...
   docker: {
      image: "zodern/meteor:root",
    },
...
  mongo: {
    version: "3.6",
    servers: {
      one: {},
    },
  },
...
```

It might be similar to this problem: [Meteor.call is very slow when responding back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67013952/meteor-call-is-very-slow-when-responding-back)

But I had never any issues with this in version 2.5.6.

Further, it only happened for method calls, all subscriptions are super quick. And it also only happened on the server! On my local dev machine, everything is good!

Does anyone know whats going on here and how I can solve this issue?

Comment: have you narrowed down where the delay is coming from? e.g., did you add `console.log`s at the start and end of the method function on the server? It would also be good to take a look at the WS in your network tab in dev console in the browser to see when you receive the DDP message with the method result.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow I missed that MongoDB is already a few versions ahead of 3.6. So i used the past hours to upgrade the server's MongoDB Version to 5.0.5 and surprise: it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He solved the issue by upgrading the server to MongoDB 5.0.5